# Dynamically assign value to dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a html page which will show the user profile username,place,about etc. I am getting the value using ajax in jquery. Now i have question how to assign retrieved value to the DOM:

**First method** would be wait till i get data then dynamically create dom and append to target div

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "profiledata",
     type: "POST",
     success:function(data){
         $("<div><label>"+data.name</label><br/>
          <label>"+data.place</label></div>").appendTo("target div");
     }
```

In this method more append of string will happen so i doubt about memory consumed by the process.

**Second method** will be just use id to assign the value:

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "profiledata",
     type: "POST",
     success:function(data){
          $("#uname").text(data.name);
          $("#place").text(data.place);
     }

 <div><label id="uname"></label><br/>
<label id="place"></label></div>
```

Which one will be efficient in terms of loading the page i.e. lighter code and page
Did i mentioned some write approach? or some better solution is there?

Comment: 6 of one half a dozen of the other, depends on your usage and which is more readable. I don't believe there will be any **significant** difference in performance.

Comment: In the first method, all of `"<div><label>"+data.name</label><br/><label>"+data.place</label></div>"` will have to be parsed by jQuery before being appended. I'd say the second is more efficient.

Comment: Depending on the complexity of the project, it might be worthwhile to use one of the many Javascript MV* frameworks, which allow you to easily bind your DOM to data sources. Some examples are [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/), [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/), and [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/). These allow you to just pull the data from the server and not worry about updating the DOM; the framework does that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the use case, both solutions have advantages and disadvantages.

The first method:

- Doesn't load the elements until you need them
- But it also has JQuery creating the element in memory rather than modifying elements on the page.

The second method:

- Isn't creating the elements so modifying the markup is a little easier as we aren't looking for html in the js.
- Now we have to remember to hide the elements if we don't want the user to see them

Which method that I would use, would depend on varying factors.  Generally, I prefer the second because then when I want to modify the markup, I am not looking in the javascript.

Comment: does that mean if i have some fixed DOM like user profile that always be same we should use second approach and if its dynamic DOM like showing comments that keeps changing, should use first one

Comment: As a general rule, yeah I would go with something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Manipulating DOM repeateadly often involves overhead. From that perspective the first method seems more appropriate.
As far as the speed of the ajax call is concerned, the data is retrieved in the same fashion in both the methods, you could use `.ajaxStart()` and `.ajaxStop()` to have 'loading' kind of effect.